# Converting cell values to snake_case

Tags: regex, excel, vba, string

I have some data cleansing task. I have a column which start from H6 and further down from their. The column contains data which was supposed to be in snake_case, but is not the case. The cell values are of the form:

- With camel case: "CamelCase"
- With spaces: "Spaced Value"
- With some initial call caps: ALLCAPSPREFIX_rest
- Combination of above

I know there mat not be concrete algo to bring this all to snake_case, but I want to come up with code which will at least bring most cells to snake_case.

I tried VBA code to replace spaces with underscores and gets the index of underscores. Now I was thinking to make all character just after underscores to be lower case. Further I was thinking to replace sequence of two characters: first lower case and next in uppercase, say `lC` to `l_c` as I dont want `CCC` to get converted to `c_c_c`, but to `ccc`. But before moving further, I want to know if there can be simpler approach to this.

Comment: I think your approach can work.  But how will you differentiated spaced values between those that should be spaced vs those that should be converted?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld didnt get you.

Comment: You provided no examples of your data, so my caveat may be superfluous.

Comment: But still want to know example you were pointing at. Also my approach requires complex string processing which I am uncomfortable with.

Comment: I was wondering how you would tell if `Spaced Value` was a string that needed to be converted to snake case, or if it should just be left alone as two separate words.

Comment: Also Regular Expressions can sometimes be useful in complicated string processing. But you have to be very clear on all the rules.

Comment: It looks as if you want to turn the string to lower case, match all letter chunks, make their first letters upper and then join them with `_`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one method that might do what you want:

```
Option Explicit
Function Snake_case(s As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=[ _A-Z])[ _]?(\S+)"
    Const sRepl As String = "$1_$2"
    Dim v As Variant

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = sPat
    v = Split(.Replace(s, sRepl), "_")
End With

v(0) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(v(0))
v(1) = LCase(v(1))
Snake_case = Join(v, "_")

End Function
```

[image]

And here is an explanation of the regex and replacement strings:

### Snake_case conversion

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=[ _A-Z])[ _]?(\S+)
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baCrn.png) `([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

  - [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
    - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
    - [A character in the range between “a” and “z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `a-z`
    - [A character in the range between “0” and “9”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `0-9`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=[ _A-Z])`

  - [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[ _A-Z]`

    - [A single character from the list “ _”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `_`
    - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
- [Match a single character from the list “ _”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[ _]?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baCrn.png) `(\S+)`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

$1_$2

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the character “_” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `_`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Quick question: if I want to also remove any non-alphanumeric from the words being snake_cased (for example, List Option(s) -> list_options), how would I do that in the regexp? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Luchadeer I suggest you process the string to do that before feeding it into the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Ron Rosenfeld solution didn't work for me. I used this one instead. Took similar on forum https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/camelcase-to-proper-case.381040/

```
Option Explicit
Function ToSnakeCase(txt As String) As String
'
' If cell A1 contains: SanFrancisco
' cell B1: =ToSnakeCase(A1)
' cell B1: San_Francisco
'
Dim Hold As String, i As Long
Hold = Left(txt, 1)
For i = 2 To Len(txt) Step 1
  If Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) > 96 Then
    Hold = Hold & Mid(txt, i, 1)
  Else
    Hold = Hold & "_" & Mid(txt, i, 1)
  End If
Next i
ToSnakeCase = Hold
End Function
```